# How can I improve this Linq query (a kind of pivoting)?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this entity:

```
public  class Delivery
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to display the deliveries by week, so i write this query:

```
    public override IEnumerable GetModelData(ApplicationDbContext context)
            {
                return context.Deliveries.GroupBy(x => x.Product).Select(x => new
                {
                    Id=x.Key.Id,
                    Product = x.Key.Name,
                    Wk1 =(int?) x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 1).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
...
...
...
                    Wk46 = (int?)x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 46).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                    Wk47 = (int?)x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 47).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                    Wk48 = (int?)x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 48).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                    Wk49 = (int?)x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 49).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                    Wk50 = (int?)x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 50).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                    Wk51 = (int?)x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 51).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                    Wk52 = (int?)x.Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 52).Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                }).ToList();
            }
```

Is it possible to get the expected object with a smaller query?

I have in this moment around 100 samples row in delivery database table, and I have the filling that this way to get the data is not the best one.

The query is working, I only want to know if you have in mind a better way to write this kind of query.

Comment: I don't understand your logic or your code. you say you want to display the deliveries by week.  can you elaborate more? what are `Wk1, Wk2 , etc`?

Comment: I am displaying a table with 53 columns, First Column is ProductName, and next 52 columns are the weeks of a year, from week1(wk1) to week52(wk52). In above query I deleted some lines in order to display a smaller query.

Comment: Wow, have you checked the generated SQL? I would expect it to be a monster due to 52 `Where` statements on the grouping result. What ORM are you using btw?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework, and yes is a huge, huge ... query :(

Comment: Any performance issues? It might be better to get the non pivoted grouped data with L2E query and do the pivoting in memory.

Comment: Instead of writing 52 where statements do another grouping by `a.DeliveryDate`

Comment: @IvanStoev What is L2E?

Comment: Linq To Entities :) vs L2O (Linq to Objects)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary can you show me a sample code, I do not get how to have same object if I group by week number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make LINQ query shorter I see is to generate the selector programmatically.

However there is definitely a way to make the generated SQL query shorter (and more efficient). Instead of `Where(condition).Sum(expr)` construct which does not translate well, use conditional sum, i.e. `Sum(condition ? expr : null)` which produces much better SQL:

```
Wk1 = x.Sum(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 1 ? a.Quantity : (int?)null),
Wk2 = x.Sum(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", a.DeliveryDate) == 2 ? a.Quantity : (int?)null),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the grouping in the SQL query, but then do the pivoting in memory.

```
public static IEnumerable GetModelData(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    return context.Deliveries
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Product.Id, x.Product.Name, Week = SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", x.DeliveryDate) } )
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Key.Id,
            Product = x.Key.Name,
            Week = x.Key.Week,
            Quantity = x.Sum(a => a.Quantity),
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Product })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Key.Id,
            Product = x.Key.Product,
            Wk1 = x.Sum(a => a.Week == 1 ? a.Quantity : 0),
            Wk2 = x.Sum(a => a.Week == 2 ? a.Quantity : 0),
            Wk51 = x.Sum(a => a.Week == 52 ? a.Quantity : 0),
            Wk52 = x.Sum(a => a.Week == 53 ? a.Quantity : 0),
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Everything above the .AsEnumerable() is executed as 1 SQL statement against the database, and everything below it is executed in memory.

Here is a trace of the SQL that gets executed.

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [ProductId],
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [Name],
    [GroupBy1].[K3] AS [C1],
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Join1].[K1] AS [K1],
        [Join1].[K2] AS [K2],
        [Join1].[K3] AS [K3],
        SUM([Join1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [K1],
            [Extent2].[Name] AS [K2],
            DATEPART(wk, [Extent1].[DeliveryDate]) AS [K3],
            [Extent1].[Quantity] AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[Deliveries] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        )  AS [Join1]
        GROUP BY [K1], [K2], [K3]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

If you remove the .AsEnumerable(), it will run all on the server.  Here is the SQL trace.

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy2].[K1] AS [ProductId],
    [GroupBy2].[K2] AS [Name],
    [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C1],
    [GroupBy2].[A2] AS [C2],
    [GroupBy2].[A3] AS [C3],
    [GroupBy2].[A4] AS [C4]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [K1],
        [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [K2],
        SUM([GroupBy1].[A1]) AS [A1],
        SUM([GroupBy1].[A2]) AS [A2],
        SUM([GroupBy1].[A3]) AS [A3],
        SUM([GroupBy1].[A4]) AS [A4]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [K1],
            [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [K2],
            CASE WHEN (1 = [GroupBy1].[K3]) THEN [GroupBy1].[A1] ELSE 0 END AS [A1],
            CASE WHEN (2 = [GroupBy1].[K3]) THEN [GroupBy1].[A1] ELSE 0 END AS [A2],
            CASE WHEN (52 = [GroupBy1].[K3]) THEN [GroupBy1].[A1] ELSE 0 END AS [A3],
            CASE WHEN (53 = [GroupBy1].[K3]) THEN [GroupBy1].[A1] ELSE 0 END AS [A4]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Join1].[K1] AS [K1],
                [Join1].[K2] AS [K2],
                [Join1].[K3] AS [K3],
                SUM([Join1].[A1]) AS [A1]
                FROM ( SELECT
                    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [K1],
                    [Extent2].[Name] AS [K2],
                    DATEPART(wk, [Extent1].[DeliveryDate]) AS [K3],
                    [Extent1].[Quantity] AS [A1]
                    FROM  [dbo].[Deliveries] AS [Extent1]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                )  AS [Join1]
                GROUP BY [K1], [K2], [K3]
            )  AS [GroupBy1]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
        GROUP BY [K1], [K2]
    )  AS [GroupBy2]
```